# Is there an API function to check whether a specific user is logged in?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there a Drupal API function that accepts a user ID and returns whether that user is currently logged in?

i.e. Is there a function like `user_is_logged_in($some_uid)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, if you want one you will have to write it yourself.  Take a look at the sessions table in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function I borrowed/modified from the advanced forum module to check if a specific user is online. It checks the sessions table for users within a certain time interval. Add it to a custom module and call as needed:

```
function MODULENAME_check_user_online($uid) {

  $interval = REQUEST_TIME - variable_get('user_block_seconds_online', 900);

  $query = db_select("users", "u")->distinct()->fields("u", array("uid", "name"));
  $s_alias = $query->join("sessions", "s", "u.uid = s.uid");

  $query->addExpression("MAX({$s_alias}.timestamp)", "maxtime");
  $query
      ->condition("{$s_alias}.timestamp", $interval, ">=")
      ->condition("{$s_alias}.uid", $uid, "=")
      ->groupBy("u.uid, u.name")
      ->orderBy("maxtime", "DESC");

  $check_user_logged_in = $query->execute();
  if ($account = $check_user_logged_in->fetchObject()) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the user module API here:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/6

more specifically
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/6

Comment: `user_is_logged_in()` only checks the global (current) user. I'd like to check by a `uid` as parameter.